# How to make "php if" for views block?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I'm generate views content with this:

```
<?php echo views_get_view('xtr')->preview('block_1', array(1)); ?>
```

But I need to add `slidewrap` class only if the content available.

Below is what I've tried which not working:

```
<?php if (views_get_view('xtr')->preview('block_1', array(1))): ?>
  <div class="slidewrap"><?php echo views_get_view('xtr')->preview('block_1', array(1)); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if your views output have contents use following snippet

```
<?php
 $view = views_get_view_result($name, $display, $args);
 $result = count($view);
 if ($result) {
   //do your stuff here
 }
?>
```